# PHP - Duplicate results when using search bar

Tags: php, search, duplicates, rows

```
$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);
foreach($search_exploded as $search_each){
    $x++;
    if($x==1) 
        $construct .="concat_ws(Name, Summary, Description, OpeningHours, Address, Postcode, Keywords) LIKE '%$search_each%' ";
    else
        $construct .="AND concat_ws(Name, Summary, Description, OpeningHours, Address, Postcode, Keywords) LIKE '%$search_each%' ";
}

$construct ="SELECT * FROM Rating, Attraction WHERE $construct" ;
$run = mysql_query($construct);
$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

if ($foundnum==0)
    echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for '$search'" ;
else
{
    echo "";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){
        echo '<a href="details.php?ID=' . $row['AttractionID'] . '"><img class="attractionimg" src="'. $row['ImageUrl'] . '" height="160" width="210" /></a>';
        echo '<div class="a-textcontain">';
        echo '<h2><a href="details.php?ID=' . $row['AttractionID'] . '">' . $row['Name'] . '</a></h2>'; 
        echo '<p class="a-text">' . $row['Summary'] . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<img class="rating" src="'. $row['RatingUrl'] . '" height="25" width="140" alt="Rating"/>';
        echo '<div class="aborderline"></div>';
        break;
    }
}
```

---

I have 12 rows of data in my database. When I search it is working correctly but repeating each search result 12 times. I have tried putting a 'break;' in like you can see above but this then limits the search to only one result...

Anyone have any ideas?

---

$construct  = "SELECT Attraction.*, Type.TypeName, Rating.RatingUrl ";

$construct .= "FROM Attraction ";

$construct .= "INNER JOIN Type ON Attraction.Type = Type.TypeID ";

$construct .= "INNER JOIN Rating ON Attraction.AttractionID = Rating.AttractionID ";

$construct .= "WHERE Attraction = $construct" ;

Comment: Can you remove all those extraneous blank lines so the whole thing would fit on one screen at once?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Rating, Attraction
> ```

You're doing a multi-table query in which each row of `Rating` is joined to each row of `Attraction`, multiplying the results. You will want a `LEFT JOIN` query with a specific join condition or possibly something else, depending on what the intent is.

See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html.

Comment: I thought it was something to do with that but I cannot write the WHERE for the $construct query, I have it like this and it doesnt work

Comment: ...? Does that mean you don't know how to apply this solution?

Comment: sorry, I have put edited the post, putting in the code that I cannot structure with the WHERE and $construct query, thanks a lot for your help!